# Single Query to get values from Sql server 2008 table based on Birthdate(dd/mmm). User will not specify Year

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

```
iEndDate = Year(Now)
For iStartDate As Int32 = 1900 To iEndDate
StartDate = Format(dtpSD.Value, "dd/MMM") + "/" + iStartDate.ToString
EndDate = Format(dtpED.Value, "dd/MMM") + "/" + iStartDate.ToString
lSql = lSql & " And" & " MD.MD_DOB >= '" & StartDate.ToString & "' AND MD.MD_DOB <= '" & EndDate.ToString & "'"
                    Next
```

I need those cut off that 'for' loop and make that query in single query.
I cant use Stored Procedure. `Environment - VB.Net , SQL Serve 2008`
For Example ,

```
User start date : 16/2/1900
End Date : 16/3/2014.
```

Results Based on :

```
16/2/1900-16/3/1900
16/2/1901-16/3/1901
16/2/1902-16/3/1902
.
.
.
16/2/2014-16/3/2014
```

Retrieve records based on that date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get days and numeric values of month and use next `WHERE` clause

```
...
WHERE MONTH(MD.MD_DOB) > @StartMonth AND MONTH(MD.MD_DOB) < @EndMonth
OR (MONTH(MD.MD_DOB) = @StartMonth AND DAY(MD.MD_DOB) >= @Startday)
OR (MONTH(MD.MD_DOB) = @EndMonth AND DAY(MD.MD_DOB) <= @Endday)
```

You don't need to set year in the `WHERE` because you want all years which are in database

Comment: this won't work precisely, for example, start = "28/02" and end = "06/03", date "27/03" will be in the output as well...

Answer (score 0):

I would say you can use a fixed year, for instance:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '2000-02-01'
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = '2000-03-31';

WITH    cal
      AS ( SELECT   *,
                    CAST('2000-' + CAST(MONTH(BirthDate) AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(DAY(BirthDate) AS VARCHAR) AS DATETIME) FakeBirthday
           FROM     yourTable
         )
SELECT  *
FROM    cal
WHERE   FakeBirthday >= @startDate AND
        FakeBirthday <= @endDate
```

2000 is used here - but it could be up to your preference. as long as it's a valid year in sql...

Comment: actually it has to be a leap year, taking 29/02 into consideration

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    MD
WHERE   Left(Convert(nvarchar(25), MD.MD_DOB, 101), 5) between Left(Convert(nvarchar(25), @StartDate, 101), 5)
        And Left(Convert(nvarchar(25), @EndDate, 101), 5)
```

Comment: this will be slower if we are talking with huge records since the code above will bypass index.  If performance is concern add new column that holds Month and Day of birth only and add an index.